# How to use FFmpegMediaPlayer ? (Windows|Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I tried to use the lib prebuilt, but couldn't, I got error on - `FFmpegMediaPlayer mp = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();`

OR can somebody to recommend good Android MediaPlayer(minSdkVersion >=9) library for playing stream audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GIT URL for FFmpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer)

have sample code :

```
    FFmpegMediaPlayer mp = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new FFmpegMediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(FFmpegMediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();         
    }
});
mp.setOnErrorListener(new FFmpegMediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onError(FFmpegMediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.release();
        return false;
    }
});

try {
    mp.setDataSource("<some path or URL>");
    mp.prepareAsync();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i know, i got error on - FFmpegMediaPlayer mp = new FFmpegMediaPlayer(); - line. LOGCAT says something about native library(can't find i think, forgot)

Comment: provide logs .. exact : native library(can't find i think, forgot) .Are you build it again. with Ant.

Comment: "Note: The build instructions and scripts assume you are running Unix or Linux. Building on other operating systems is currently not supported." - i work with windows && haven't linux|unix

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-fplayer/source/browse/trunk/src/cz/havlena/ffmpeg/ui?spec=svn2&r=2
one of link help you

Comment: it it will work , update the answer so other person will get help

Comment: Finally i can to integrate FFmpegMediaPlayer, working fine.